# I get "Background sticky concurrent mark sweep G" in logs and then nothing happens

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to connect to a FTP server and displaying data on my android app after pulling it from the server, but I have not been able to figure it out. I am facing the above mentioned problem. FTPDownloader class is inside the MainActivity Class and I call it by 
***new FTPDownloader().execute();***. I call the doInBackground() of FTPDownloader() after pressing a button in MainActivity class. But nothing happens as if the doInBackground() method never ran. The app does not freeze though but nothing happens either. Thanks in advance, any help appreciated.

```
   private class FTPDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        FTPClient ftp = null;
        InputStream in;

        public FTPDownloader() {
            ftp = null;
        }


        public void disconnect() {
            if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    this.ftp.logout();
                    this.ftp.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException f) {
                    // do nothing as file is already downloaded from FTP server
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {

                ftp = new FTPClient();
                ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
                int reply;
                ftp.connect("12.123.12.123");
                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
                }
                ftp.login("user1234","1234" );
                ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                in = ftp.retrieveFileStream("filePath");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("FTP", "Error Occurred.");

            }
             try {

                int data = in.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    String s = "";
                    char ch = (char) data;
                    if (ch != ',') {
                        s = s + ch;
                    } else {
                        s = s + " ";
                        gblprpd.add(s);
                        data = in.read();
                    }
                }
                in.close();

                for (int i = 0; i < gblprpd.size(); ++i) {
                    String s = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                        ++i;
                        s = s + gblprpd.get(i);
                    }

                    dta.add(s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("FTP", "Error Occurred");

            }

            disconnect();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void cd) {


                    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                    output.setText("Data Retrieved:");
                    for (int k = 0; k < dta.size(); ++k) {
                        roes.get(k + 1).setText(dta.get(k));
                    }
                    for (int k = dta.size() + 1; k < 16; ++k)
                        roes.get(k).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
                    sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
                    hsv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
}


}
```

The logs are:

```
06-12 21:08:30.797 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
06-12 21:08:30.800 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: USER user1234
06-12 21:08:30.861 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 331 Password required
06-12 21:08:30.862 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: PASS 1234
06-12 21:08:30.936 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 230 User logged in.
06-12 21:08:30.938 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: TYPE I
06-12 21:08:31.018 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 200 Type set to I.
06-12 21:08:31.019 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: PASV
06-12 21:08:31.082 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 227 Entering Passive Mode (14,141,70,165,66,149).
06-12 21:08:31.145 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: RETR File\Path
06-12 21:08:31.213 23404-23469/com.example.quickstart I/System.out: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
06-12 21:08:46.814 23404-23415/com.example.quickstart I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 910864(25MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 29MB/40MB, paused 1.234ms total 106.681ms
06-12 21:08:46.976 23404-23415/com.example.quickstart I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 926388(25MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 29MB/40MB, paused 1.118ms total 104.876ms
```

Please help, any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are reading bytes off of an FTP connection in `onPostExecute()`. `onPostExecute()` is run on the main application thread. Hence, you are doing network I/O on the main application thread.

Move *all* of your code that uses the FTP connection into `doInBackground()`. Use the downloaded data in `onPostExecute()`.

Also note that you do not need `runOnUiThread()` in `onPostExecute()`, as `onPostExecute()` runs on the main application ("UI") thread already.

Comment: I changed the code as above but now I am getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" , error

Comment: @KushagrTyagi: If you still have the problem, post a separate Stack Overflow question with your newer code and your newer stack trace.

Comment: There was en error in the while loop, that was making it an infinite loop. I fixed that and it works just fine. Thanks everyone for their time and help.